# Можно ли назвать данные пространства имен корневыми?

Tags: c#, .net, namespace

Если я,к примеру, в файле проекта (.cs) объявлю неймспейсы так:

```
namespace A1
{

}

namespace B1
{

}
```

то можно ли их считать корневыми?
Если нет,то они будут считаться такими если будут иметь в себе под-пространства имен как тут:

```
namespace A1
{

    namespace A2 { }
}

namespace B1
{

    namespace B2 { }
}
```

Comment: Где Вы нашли определение «корневое» пространство имен? Распишите подробно что Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @defaultlocale точного определения я не знаю.Скорее всего я понимаю под корневым пространством имен,root namespace которое дается по дефолту новому классу(объявленному в файле .cs ).Где то прочитал,что созданные папки  в проекте,часто используются в качестве пространств имен,то есть,к примеру, у меня есть проект MyProject,и папка в нем MyFolder, и когда я добавляю в нее классы у них по дефолту неймспейсы MyProject.MyFolder,то есть неймспейс MyFolder вложен в неймспейс MyProject.Здесь,на один из моих вопросов,был добавлен комментарий,что хорошим тоном является 2 корневых пространства имен.

Comment: @defaultlocale не знаю будет ли этот пример корректен. Неймспейс System будет корневым для пространства имен  System.IO

Comment: Получается, что корневое пространство это то ли глобальное (`global::`, по-умолчанию) то ли родительское. Но тогда в чем смысл вопроса? Зачем Вам знать чем можно считать `A1` и `B1`? Какую проблему Вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @defaultlocale я пытаюсь понять,получается есть глобальное пространство имен и объявленные пространства имен в проекте(к примеру мной) ,которые делят глобальный неймспейс на независимые части.Корневое пространство имен является корневым по отношению ко вложенному в него неймспейсу.Это верно или нет?

Comment: «Корневое пространство имен является корневым ...» Это тавтология :) Вы только что на ходу придумали называть «корневым» пространство, в которое что-то вложено. Проблема в том, что до сих пор непонятно (1) где Вы нашли это определение, в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces) ничего внятного про это нет (2) в чем смысл этого вопроса? Какая разница как называть эти пространства?

Comment: @defaultlocale повторюсь,точного определения я не знаю,я нашел в гугл картинках http://bit.do/fG77f (ссылку сократил).Получается так нельзя говорить,есть просто пространства имен,которые объявляются папками в проекте?

Comment: @defaultlocale можете посоветовать где можно про пространства имен прочитать,желательно не документация майкрософт

Comment: По [ссылке](https://slide-share.ru/yazik-c-platforma-net-visual-studio-80840) слово «корневой» используется в разговорном смысле: `System` является общим корнем для всех пространств в *стандартной* библиотеке .net. Говорить можно все что угодно, если хотите называть `A1` корневым — называйте. Просто вопрос теряет смысл без внятного определения.

Comment: Посмотрите [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c) . Рекоммендую обратить внимание на «CLR via C#» Рихтера. Только помните, что начинающему программисту нужно писать как можно больше кода. Теория становится яснее когда применяешь ее в деле. И да, официальную документацию тоже придется изучать.

Comment: @defaultlocale вообще ,что я имел в виду под своим вопросом: есть ли какое-либо правило,соглашение, как правильно объявлять пространства имен;где их размещать(в отдельных папках проекта или просто файлах .cs);сколько,желательно,объявлять(хороший тон) и т.п

Answer (score 2):

В документации нет определения «корневого» пространства имен в общем случае. Есть глобальное пространство имен `global::`, но оно используется в других ситуациях.

Пространства имен существуют для группировки типов по смыслу в Вашем коде. Формально, нет никакой «жесткой» связи между пространствами имен и файловой системой. Можете разложить классы по разным папкам, но объявить их в одном пространстве имен. И наоборот, можете в одном файле объявить десять разных пространств.

### Вложенные пространства

Та конструкция, которую Вы описали называется [вложенные пространства имен](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces) (nested namespaces).

Говоря о вложенных пространствах имен нужно понимать, что конструкция

```
namespace A1
{
    namespace A2 { }
}
```

Равнозначна конструкции:

```
namespace A1 {}

//пространства могут быть в разных файлах и разных папках
namespace A1.A2 {}
```

Единственная разница: в первом случае, если в пространстве `A1` объявлен класс, то его можно использовать в A1.A2 без `using`:

```
namespace A1 
{
    class Class1 {}
    namespace A2 
    {
         class Class2 
         {
              //используем класс из «родителя»
              Class1 class1;
         }
    }
}
```

, а во втором случае придется прописать `using`:

```
namespace A1 
{
    class Class1 {}
}

//другой файл
using A1;        // единственное отличие
namespace A2 
{
    class Class2 
    {
         Class1 class1;
    }
}
```

При желании можно `A1` здесь назвать «корнем» иерархии пространств имен A1->A2. Но это слово приобретает больше смысла в более узком контексте.

### Корневое пространство имен

Корневое пространство имен имеет больше смысла когда речь идет о конкретном проекте или о группе проектов.

Если Вы пишете проект с множеством классов, то логично будет сгруппировать их в несколько разных пространств имен по смыслу. Например, собрать классы по работе с базой данных в пространство имен `Database`, относящиеся к интерфейсу в `UI`.

Но при этом будет лучше если все пространства имен будут иметь некий общий префикс. Например, если Вы разрабатываете игру «Сапер»: `Minesweeper.UI`, `Minesweeper.Database`.

Этот подход удобен тем, что типы Вашего проекта заметно отличаются от типов из стандартной библиотеки (`System`) и от типов в используемых библиотеках (у них будут свои префиксы). Это значит что их будет легче найти по имени при написании кода. Это также снижает вероятность пересечения имен классов в разных проектах.

В нашем примере `Minesweeper` будет общим префиксом для пространства имен проекта «Сапер» и, соответственно, корневым пространством имен для всех типов этого проекта.

Но это еще не все, разработчик (компания или человек) может решить, что все его проекты должны иметь общее наименование. Так он сможет выпускать свои проекты для широкой аудитории и быть уверен, что имена его типов будут уникальны (разных реализаций «Сапера» может быть много) и узнаваемы. Так, компания StackOverflow может решить, что все пространства имен в их проектах будут начинаться со `Stackoverflow.`. «Сапер», выпущенный в этой компании будет иметь пространства имен: `Stackoverflow.Minesweeper.UI`, `Stackoverflow.Minesweeper.Database`.

Т.о. получаем, что корневое пространство имен, это общий префикс нескольких пространств имен: в каком-то проекте или в какой-то компании.

### Visual Studio

В свойствах проекта Visual Studio есть пространство имен по-умолчанию. По умолчанию его название совпадает с именем проекта, но его можно изменить. Visual Studio и другие редакторы кода часто ожидают, что пространства имен соотвествуют файловой системе. Если Вы создатите проект `First`, внутри него папку `Second`, а в ней класс `Third`, то скорее всего среда подставит ему пространство имен `First.Second`.

Таким образом Visual Studio помогает Вам создать общее пространство имен для всех типов проекта. По причинам описаным выше это хорошая практика.

### Хорошие практики

Хорошие практики всегда субъективны. По поводу пространств имен есть много руководств и рекомендаций: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481697/net-best-practices-guidelines-for-dividing-namespaces-between-files), [3](https://google.github.io/styleguide/csharp-style.html#namespace-naming).

Смысл хороших практик в том, чтобы классы было легче найти и отличать друг от друга.

Я бы предложил ориентироваться на достаточно короткий принятый ответ здесь: [Should the folders in a solution match the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664/should-the-folders-in-a-solution-match-the-namespace). Немного перефразирую его:

- По возможности создавайте один тип  на один .cs файл. В файле `Simple.cs` должен находиться класс или структура `Simple`.
- Иерархия пространств имен должна совпадать с файловой системой. Класс в папке `First` должен иметь пространство имен, заканчивающееся на `.First`.
- У каждого проекта/сборки должно быть одно корневое пространство имен, в котором будут находится все типы в проекте/сборке. Имя этого пространства должно совпадать с именем проекта.
- Группируйте типы по смыслу и давайте осмысленные имена типам и пространствам имен.

Для начинающего программиста эти правила будут неплохим началом. Пишите много кода, читайте книги и изучайте документацию и постепенно Вы поймете чем эти правила хороши и в каких случаях имеет смысл их нарушать.

Comment: "У каждого проекта/сборки должно быть одно корневое пространство имен, в котором будут находится все типы в проекте/сборке. Имя этого пространства должно совпадать с именем проекта.", но бывают исключения как, mscorlib.dll к примеру?

Comment: @n_enrai49 Естественно, это рекомендация, не более. Суть в том, что для того чтобы отступать от этого правила нужен какой-то повод.